# Persistent client-side data storage with specified expiration

Tags: javascript, cookies, persistent-storage

I am searching for a client-side persistent data storage method that is common across a large number of browsers and allows the specification of an expiration date, like that of document.cookies. I have looked at windows.localStorage (cannot limit expiration) and windows.sessionStorage (expiration occurs too soon) and, for the reasons stated, have decided not to use them. This leaves me with document.cookies. The major problem appears to be that cookies can be blocked. The EU cookie policy appears not to place restrictions on session cookies that are used internally within the site. In the current design, a visitor who blocks cookies will see only an insignificant loss of functionality.

So is there another method of client-side persistent data storage, other than document.cookies, that might be recommended?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `localStorage` and include a timestamp with each value you store. Then, when you're reading the value, check the timestamp and see if it's too old to be considered.

```
function storeInLocalStorage(key, val, msLifespan){
    window.localStorage.setItem(key, (new Date().getTime() + msLifespan) + "|" + val);
}

function getFromLocalStorage(key){
    var item = window.localStorage.getItem(key);
    if(item === null) return null;

    var expiration = Number(item.substring(0, item.indexOf("|")));
    if(new Date().getTime() < expiration) return item.substring(item.indexOf("|") + 1);
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the thought, however the expiration date that I seek is something like a session cookie. Thus when the browser closes, the cookie is deleted. Using your method would require a browser closing event handler, a little more complicated than I had planned. Thanks for your thoughts.